# Why pyautogui.locateOnScreen is not working for new png?

Tags: python, screenshot, pyautogui

I am writing a code for HayDay. I found the [original code](https://github.com/jojo2504/Hayday-Bot) on github and make some change on it. The only thing I did is change some picture in the file, and open the file on my screen to see if they can be detdetected. The problem is that all the origin png in the file works well, but the ones I added all do not work(cannot be detected).

```
import pyautogui
def locateOnScreen(needle, confidence_threshold, x=400, y=200, width=1100, height=600):
    return pyautogui.locateOnScreen(needle, region=(x, y, width, width), grayscale=True, confidence=confidence_threshold)
png_list = [
    'countdown_free_publication',  # 0
    'end_list_shop',  # 1
    'farmland',  # 2
    'free_publication',  # 3
    'free_publication2',  # 4
    'full_silo',  # 5
    'initialization_crop',  # 6
    'new_sell',  # 7
    'planting_wheat',  # 8
    'published_wheat',  # 9
    'road',  # 10
    'scytheV2',  # 11
    'selled',  # 12
    'shop',  # 13
    'shop_presence',  # 14
    'unpublished_wheat',  # 15
    'wheat',  # 16
    'WTF ARE WE DOING HERE'  # 17
]
for confidence_level in [x * 0.01 for x in range(70, 95)]:
    imgnum = 12
    item_publishable_result = locateOnScreen(f'images/{png_list[imgnum]}.png', confidence_threshold=confidence_level)

    if item_publishable_result != None:
        item_publishable_x = item_publishable_result.left
        item_publishable_y = item_publishable_result.top
        print(f"png:{png_list[imgnum]}    confi:{confidence_level}   Find one in {item_publishable_x}, {item_publishable_y}")

    else:
        print(f"confi:{confidence_level}   Can't find")
```

this code was to test the suitable confidence_threshold, but it accidentally finds the bug, if anyone want to run this code, just change "imgnum"'s number, and maybe add some pigture in the file to see if the code can detect them.

I keep all the variable the same but the png in the file. Technically, I think it should always able to detect itself, but the truth is not. Also, when I write the pyautogui.locateOnScreen code by myself, it does not work either(also some teaching template pyautogui.locateOnScreen code copy from others). I just want the picture finding code work :(